# how to convert the post request from xml to json in a restful web service

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

```
@POST    
@Path("/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String createUser(@FormParam("id") int id,
@FormParam("name") String name,
@FormParam("profession") String profession,
@Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException{
User user = new User(id, name, profession);
int result = userDao.addUser(user);
if(result == 1){
return SUCCESS_RESULT;
}
return FAILURE_RESULT;
}
```

**strong text**

reference : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_methods.htm

Comment: What do you mean by _convert_?

Comment: I mean I want to produce and consume the above code using json

Comment: First thing you need to do is to add a JSON provider to your project. Then change the `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML` to `APPLICATION_JSON`.

Comment: @Paul Samsotha :                                                                                        
         I tried but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Produces and consumes are the sharing content-Type and Accept headers.
You can go ahead and get the input as application/Json.
But i will give you the conversion of XML to JSON
Load the XML with jaxb

```
Catalog catalog = JAXB.unmarshal(new File(xmlFile), Catalog.class);
```

Now you have to serialize the java object

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(System.out, catalog);
```

You are done.!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a value as JSON please remove the
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
And use         @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
instead of XML. In default media type is always a JSON
But in your code, you are returning a STRING value which is not at all a JSON. If you insist to return a string value please use            @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    it will return a String equivalent of MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.

Comment: can you make it clear, I have tried using @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).

Comment: and in my case i'm returning an object

Comment: if @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) doesnot return the result please use @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)  whiich will convert return json

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    at method level
```

and use

```
@XMLRootElement
```

at pojo class level